# Why does my Mac Mini (2012) lock up with a fresh Mavericks install?

Tags: macos, mac-mini

I've reinstalled OS X Mavericks from scratch twice on my (usually headless) Mac Mini, but it keeps locking up after ten or fifteen minutes of use - even just Safari browsing. I use Screen Sharing with the firewall off (for now - to rule that out as a cause of the problem).

I connected an HDTV to see what was going on when the Mini locked up and I saw this:

[image]

...which doesn't look good.

I've run a full 'memtest' in single-user mode, twice, and that says it's OK. I'll try AHT when I get the chance, but does anyone have any advice or suggestions as to the cause?

Comment: Looks like a graphics driver problem.  Is there any messages visible with the Console.app tool after reboot?

Comment: Well, nothing that looks like any specific error regarding drivers. Looks like mostly startup messages and some screen sharing authentication... All I've done is install Mavericks and enable Screen Sharing. No other settings or software have been changed or installed.

Comment: It was a long shot.  Has it ever worked as expected?  What have you changed since then?  (New RAM/harddisk/extra USB devices)?

Comment: I picked it up second-hand last week, and have upgraded it to 8GB Crucial RAM. Also added an SSD which is running with the original HDD as a Fusion drive. No USB devices connected other than the keyboard :)

Comment: Macs are very picky about SSD-drives.  Try going back to the original HDD only.

Comment: Interesting ... it's an OWC Extreme Pro 6G, and I've not had a problem adding those to Macs before (this'll be my fourth), but I'll try your suggestion anyway - thanks!

Comment: Well, in the process of removing and replacing the SSD to test it, I found that the problem was caused by not-quite-firmly-seated RAM - so thank you!

Comment: The AHT should have caught that.  You could also have booted on a Memtest86+ media (like the Ubuntu cd) and tested with that.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found that the problem was caused by not-quite-firmly-seated RAM.

Comment: Crazy that memtest was OK but the GPU wasn't ok. Glad it was an easy fix. I'm always relieved, sometimes shocked, and often pleased when reseating RAM and/or reseating cables clears up reproducible glitches.